# Change column to multi-index by using one column as a new level

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Close': {1: 14.03, 3: 14.02, 0: 79.88, 2: 80.31},
 'High': {1: 14.3, 3: 14.33, 0: 80.22, 2: 81.19},
 'Low': {1: 14.03, 3: 13.99, 0: 79.39, 2: 80.25},
 'Open': {1: 14.18, 3: 14.25, 0: 79.79, 2: 80.97},
 'Volume': {1: 1656782.0, 3: 2249159.0, 0: 1416232.0, 2: 1622784.0},
 'Value': {1: 23244651.46, 3: 31533209.18, 0: 113128612.16, 2: 130325783.04},
 'Code': {1: 'A2M', 3: 'A2M', 0: 'CBA', 2: 'CBA'}})
df.index = [0,1,0,1]

    Close   High    Low     Open    Volume      Value           Code
0   14.03   14.30   14.03   14.18   1656782.0   2.324465e+07    A2M
1   14.02   14.33   13.99   14.25   2249159.0   3.153321e+07    A2M
0   79.88   80.22   79.39   79.79   1416232.0   1.131286e+08    CBA
1   80.31   81.19   80.25   80.97   1622784.0   1.303258e+08    CBA
```

How Can I change the column as a multi index with the values from Code column as the first level and the current column as the second level?

```
        CBA                                                         A2M
        Close   High    Low     Open    Volume      Value           Close   High    Low     Open    Volume      Value                                           
0       79.88   80.22   79.39   79.79   1416232.0   1.131286e+08    14.02   14.33   13.99   14.25   2249159.0   31533209.18
1       80.31   81.19   80.25   80.97   1622784.0   1.303258e+08    14.03   14.30   14.03   14.18   1656782.0   23244651.46
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), then [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Code', append=True).unstack().swaplevel(1, 0, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
Code    A2M                                                 CBA                \
      Close   High    Low   Open        Value     Volume  Close   High    Low   
0     14.03  14.30  14.03  14.18  23244651.46  1656782.0  79.88  80.22  79.39   
1     14.02  14.33  13.99  14.25  31533209.18  2249159.0  80.31  81.19  80.25   

Code                                  
       Open         Value     Volume  
0     79.79  1.131286e+08  1416232.0  
1     80.97  1.303258e+08  1622784.0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use your `index` to use [`GroupBy.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df.groupby(['Code',df.index]).first().unstack('Code').swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)

Code    A2M                                                 CBA                \
      Close   High    Low   Open        Value     Volume  Close   High    Low   
0     14.03  14.30  14.03  14.18  23244651.46  1656782.0  79.88  80.22  79.39   
1     14.02  14.33  13.99  14.25  31533209.18  2249159.0  80.31  81.19  80.25   

Code                                  
       Open         Value     Volume  
0     79.79  1.131286e+08  1416232.0  
1     80.97  1.303258e+08  1622784.0
```